# MongoDB no results filtering by a DBRef

Tags: mongodb

In this image we can see my problem:

[image]

I have a collection "Respuesta" with two DBRef, one to a collection "Parte" and other to a collection "Pregunta"...

In the image we can see that if a filter by DBref "Parte", it works fine... but then when I make the same query but filtering by DBRef "Pregunta" there is no results (but at least exists the result that I mark in red colour)

Can somebody tell me what happens?

I do this query:

```
db.Respuesta.find({pregunta: DBRef("Pregunta", ObjectId("64c1e71c80abcf083d007a36"), "symfony")}).pretty()
```

At least I expected to see the result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64c24d0880abcf083d007a61"),
    "parte" : DBRef("Parte", ObjectId("64c205df80abcf083d007a41"), "symfony"),
    "pregunta" : DBRef("Pregunta", ObjectId("64c1e71c80abcf083d007a36"), "symfony"),
    "respuesta" : "1"
}
```

But there is no result..

Comment: Can you try a syntax like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vHJFidkKU8P)? Interestingly when I try to replicate your scenario, it turns out that [the syntax you are currently using](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xsYZ6Jm7w2F) seems to have indeterministic behaviour. If you try to run the same query multiple times, sometimes result is returned while sometimes nothing is returned.

Comment: Thank you!! with the new syntax works great! I also test the old syntax running the same query multiple times, and it is true that sometimes returns result and others not... quite strange... Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

With the Ray comment, the filter works fine.

I have to use the following command:

```
db.Respuesta.find({"pregunta.$id": ObjectId("64c1e5e280abcf5577420340")})
```

Be careful because the first syntax that I used works randomly:

```
b.Respuesta.find({pregunta: DBRef("Pregunta", ObjectId("64c1e71c80abcf083d007a36"), "symfony")}).pretty()
```