# MongoDB - inconsistent query behaviour when querying by DBRef

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This question stems from another question that I have worked on: [MongoDB no results filtering by a DBRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76839245/mongodb-no-results-filtering-by-a-dbref?noredirect=1#comment135466841_76839245)

The original question is kind of solved by suggesting OP to query by `$id` field inside the DBRef. However, during the time that I try to replicate the issue, I found out that the the query behaviour is indeterministic if querying by whole DBRef object.

Sample json:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("64c24d0880abcf083d007a61"),
    "dbref": {
      "$ref": "collection2",
      "$id": ObjectId("64c1e71c80abcf083d007a36"),
      "extraField": "test"
    }
  }
]
```

query:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "dbref": {
    "$ref": "collection2",
    "$id": ObjectId("64c1e71c80abcf083d007a36"),
    "extraField": "test"
  }
})
```

Here is a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hMUIH-3HNE_) to replicate the issue.

You can press run multiple times to check the result. Sometimes the document returns while sometimes does not.

Is there an explanation for this scenario?

Edit: The scenario is not replicable on a standalone MongoDB setup. Seems like the issue is limited to Mongo playground.

Comment: I'm not sure how informative the data point of behavior being inconsistent in mongoplayground actually is. The [playground uses the Go driver](https://github.com/feliixx/mongoplayground) which does not support DBRefs according to the [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/#driver-support-for-dbrefs)

Comment: @user20042973 you made a point. However, the original question's poster is experiencing the same behaviour in his Mongo shell. That's why I believe the behaviour is not exclusive to Mongo playground.

Comment: That is weird.  There seems to be some object field ordering strangeness where comparing `JSON.stringify(dbref)` value is constant.  Well, I clicked <run> many, many times on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kam5Dvvl_Al) and it always matched.  I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: I also don't know why this [`$objectToArray` _exploration_](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uLJx3o3CckH) is inconsistent with multiple <run> clicks.

Comment: I'd recommend you try to replicate this at the DB level and not using a 3rd party tool like MongoPlayground, My guess is that the the field order is not preserved when the query gets parsed on the server side.